# Entitlement and Support Record Update Rule runing from past 2 days not complete

Tags: casemilestone, entitlements

I am running Entitlement and Support Record Update Rule after creating a new version, but its running forever and stopped incrementing at certain of point of time and stuck.

Couple of questions:
Is there any way to know still how many records are pending still to process?

What are my next steps if it stuck for so long ? I have to deploy this in prod next week.

Contacted salesforce customer support they doesn't help much.

Comment: There's no way to tell. You might need to escalate the case with support. Also, it might be useful to know how many records are in your database, at least approximately.

Comment: Is there any way for us to query on number of records in my database?

Comment: You can go to Storage Usage to get an estimate (Setup > Data Management > Storage Usage), or you can go to Developer Console (Your Name / Gear Icon > Developer Console), click on the Query tab, and type in something like `SELECT COUNT() FROM ...` (where ... is the object you're interested in).

Comment: I am trying to understand the count : I looked at cases+accounts+case milestone objects record count. Still the count doesnt match with the support records processed. Is there any other object i ma missing?